# RegistersUsers trait in Laravel 7.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to override core registration functionality in Laravel 7.23.2. According to this [source](https://laraveldaily.com/9-things-you-can-customize-in-laravel-registration/) I need to override the `register()` function, which belongs to the trait 'RegistersUsers' and is located in **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/**

However, in this folder all I see is **User.php** and **"Access"** folder which does not have the aforementioned trait as well. I've searched the entire **vendor** folder and there is no file **RegistersUsers.php**. In [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth) of Laravel Framework 7.x, there is no such file as well.

But I can see one in Laravel 5.5. So I assume registration method resides somewhere else.

So basically my two questions:

1. In registration controller there is a line `use RegistersUsers;`
   If there is no RegistersUsers.php, then what is being used here?
2. This will probably be answered by the first one, but where I can find the core implementation of `register()` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was moved out of the core and is part of the `laravel/ui` package. So the file would be in `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/`.

You can open that and see the `register` method, but you may not have to override it. That method calls other methods that you can override as well. Some of these methods are only there basically so you can override them so you don't have to override the entire Registration system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It was very helpful in a place where I would have been stuck for ages trying to figure out my way around